# Magento Colour Swatches for simple products

Tags: magento, configurable, configurable-product

I did search the site before I ask this question. But I really couldn't figure it out.

I have some products which come with a few different colours. I know I could use configurable product feature but I do want each variation display in the catalog. Here is what I want to do (and also saw a few sites doing this):

For Example, I have a blue lamp product. I want to have a colour swatch for other colours like, Red, White, Green and Red. When you click the colour swatch, it will take you to that particularly product.

How do I do it? Is there an extension available?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a native module in magento 1.9.1.0.

The name of the module you wrote correctly. You can also try to search on magento connect for 'Color swatches'

Comment: My understanding is that the colour swatches is for configurable products? I want the products to remain as simple products so customer can see it in the category? here is an example from a website I am trying to get:  http://www.festive-lights.com/battery-lights/20-white-led-silver-wire-battery-fairy-lights.html

Comment: Yes. Here is features list: https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-community-edition-191-now-available-download#.VTDmbpNKVdw - Configurable swatches enable merchants to show off a range of product attributes, such as colors,.............

Comment: Thanks! But I think that is for configurable products. My question is connecting a few simple products. I know how to use configurable. But in my case, I don't want to use them. I want to each simple product as it is but have a option to connecto/related to other colour? When choose other colour, it works like a swatches (but not through configurable). Correct me if I have misread your post.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Maybe this is suitable? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatches-for-custom-options.html

Comment: no, I don't think it is the extension I am after. but thank you very much for your help!